# Trouble with using a trait with lifetime parameter as a generic bound

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I am trying to use a trait `Context` whose different implementations allows `Cell` to access its owner `World` in different ways, as in the following contrived example code (which compiles; [playground here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=206aec20811db0706a1079db8e0724a2)):

```rust
struct Cell {    
    value: i32,    
} 
    
impl Cell {    
    fn evolve<'a>(&self, ctx: impl Context<'a>) -> Cell {    
        Cell {    
            value: self.value + ctx.get_rate()    
        }    
    }    
}    
    
struct World {    
    cell: Cell,    
    magic: i32,    
}    
    
impl World {    
    fn evolve_cell<'a, C: Context<'a>>(&'a self) -> Cell {    
        let ctx = C::new(self);        
        self.cell.evolve(ctx)        
    }    
        
    fn update(&mut self) {    
        self.cell = self.evolve_cell::<MagicContext>();    
    }    
}        
         
trait Context<'a> {    
    fn new(world: &'a World) -> Self;    
    fn get_rate(&self) -> i32;    
}    
     
struct MagicContext<'a> {    
    world: &'a World,        
}                            
                             
impl <'a> Context<'a> for MagicContext<'a> {                     
    fn new(world: &'a World) -> Self {    
        MagicContext {    
            world    
        }    
    }        
             
    fn get_rate(&self) -> i32 {    
        self.world.magic    
    }    
}        
         
fn main() {    
    let mut world = World {    
        cell: Cell { value: 2 },    
        magic: 3,    
    };    
          
    world.update();    
    println!("{}", world.cell.value);    
}
```

Instead of specifying `MagicContext` as the `Context` implementation in `World::update`, I would like to be able to choose the implementation at the call site in `main` -- something like this:

```rust
impl World {    
    // ...

    fn update<C: Context>(&mut self) {    
        self.cell = self.evolve_cell::<C>();    
    }
}

// ...

fn main() {
    // ...
    world.update::<MagicContext>();
    // ...
}
```

But `Context` needs a lifetime parameter. I can't introduce a lifetime parameter like `fn update<'a, C: Context<'a>>(&mut self)` since the context's lifetime will prevent me from mutating `self`:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `self.cell` because it is borrowed
  --> lifetime.rs:25:9
   |
24 |     fn update<'a, C: Context<'a>>(&'a mut self) {
   |               -- lifetime `'a` defined here
25 |         self.cell = self.evolve_cell::<C>();
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^-----------------------
   |         |           |
   |         |           borrow of `self.cell` occurs here
   |         |           argument requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'a`
   |         assignment to borrowed `self.cell` occurs here
```

Some seemingly similar questions led me to have a look at Higher-Rank Trait Bounds, along the lines of `fn update<C: for <'a> Context<'a>>(&mut self)`, but the compiler tells me that:

```
error: implementation of `Context` is not general enough
  --> lifetime.rs:56:11
   |
56 |     world.update::<MagicContext>();
   |           ^^^^^^ implementation of `Context` is not general enough
   |
   = note: `Context<'0>` would have to be implemented for the type `MagicContext<'_>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
   = note: ...but `Context<'1>` is actually implemented for the type `MagicContext<'1>`, for some specific lifetime `'1`
```

I would like to be able to get rid of `Context`'s lifetime parameter altogether, but I don't know how to express the `new` function without it.

How can I achieve this (or something equivalent in a more idiomatic way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be resolved using [GATs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265) ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=45077596937007babc50957915790e8e)):

```rust
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]

struct Cell {
    value: i32,
}

impl Cell {
    fn evolve(&self, ctx: impl Context) -> Cell {
        Cell {
            value: self.value + ctx.get_rate(),
        }
    }
}

struct World {
    cell: Cell,
    magic: i32,
}

impl World {
    fn evolve_cell<C: Context>(&self) -> Cell {
        let ctx = C::new(self);
        self.cell.evolve(ctx)
    }

    fn update<C: Context>(&mut self) {
        self.cell = self.evolve_cell::<C>();
    }
}

trait Context {
    type Instance<'a>: Context;
    fn new<'a>(world: &'a World) -> Self::Instance<'a>;
    fn get_rate(&self) -> i32;
}

struct MagicContext<'a> {
    world: &'a World,
}

impl<'a> Context for MagicContext<'a> {
    type Instance<'b> = MagicContext<'b>;
    
    fn new<'b>(world: &'b World) -> Self::Instance<'b> {
        MagicContext { world }
    }

    fn get_rate(&self) -> i32 {
        self.world.magic
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, GATs are unstable. There is a workaround for lifetime GATs, though: create another trait with the associated type:

```rust
trait ContextInstance<'a> {
    type Instance: Context;
}
trait Context: for<'a> ContextInstance<'a> {
    fn new<'a>(world: &'a World) -> <Self as ContextInstance<'a>>::Instance;
    fn get_rate(&self) -> i32;
}

impl<'a, 'b> ContextInstance<'b> for MagicContext<'a> {
    type Instance = MagicContext<'b>;
}
impl<'a> Context for MagicContext<'a> {
    fn new<'b>(world: &'b World) -> <Self as ContextInstance<'b>>::Instance {
        MagicContext { world }
    }

    fn get_rate(&self) -> i32 {
        self.world.magic
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cbe19fcec2a36836080bb9be5fe2bd64).